# How to pass value to completion handler in Swift?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, asynccallback

I would like to pass a integer to a completion handler.  Because the handler is asynchronous the value of count might be inaccurate by the time the completion handler gets a chance to run?  I would like to pass the CURRENT value of count to the handler so that count is accurate when the handler is called.  How do I do this?

```
// Take image
    func didPressTakePhoto(){

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){

            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

            count = count + 1

            //Capture image.  everything in this closure is ASYNCHRONOUS?
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {
                (sampleBuffer, error) in

                //Do something with count...

            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no declaration in this function for `count`, I will assume that `count` is a parameter. If so, then accessing `count` using `self.count` (mandatory in a block) will get the latest value of `count`, even if it changes after you call `captureStillImageAsynchronously()`.

If there is any chance that `count` can be written and read at the same time by multiple sources, you should ensure it is thread safe.

Comment: I declared count outside as global variable.